# How to have an ad appear in between when your app program is running

Tags: iphone, ios, iad

I would like to have an ad to appear in between your app is running.In the iAd, the ad runs in the top or the position you place your iAd Banner. At times, the user might not press the ad. However, i would like to my app to have an ad such that person have no choice but to click it. Meaning to say that the ad appears in between when the app is running and the user has to click to cancel it. In this way, he uses the ad. An example of this type of app is Touch 4. I am interested in making this type of app.

Need some guidance on how to start this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out. It is only for iPad though. (it is against the rules to do the same thing on the iPhone)

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/iAd_Guide/Full-ScreenAdvertisements/Full-ScreenAdvertisements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009881-CH5-SW1